# How do I optimize reqular expressions in JAX-RS path parameters?

Tags: java, regex, jakarta-ee

I am attempting to build a REST hierarchy leveraging regex path parameters.  I want to define an undetermined amount of parameters in path parameters e.g.

```
@Path("/param1{param1:(/?[0-9]+/?)*}/param2/{param2}/{keyVal:([a-zA-Z]+/[0-9]+/?)+}/search")
```

param1 is essentially a list of numbers separated by slashes e.g.

```
/234/5678/90112/
```

param2 is a simple number I need isolated from param1

keyVal is an indeterminate number of sets of key value pairs e.g

```
keyA/123/keyB/456/keyC/6789
```

I believe I am running into some kind of backtracking problem with param1, as adding more than 6 numbers causes considerable slow down.

A valid url for this path would like like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/service/api/param1/234/5678/90112/param2/1234/keyA/123/search
```

Is there a way to optimize this regex?

Comment: Could you just provide a sample ready-to-test regex?

Comment: I do not understand your request.  The regex is built into the path annotation. 

 `(/?[0-9]+/?)*`  tries to match param1
`([a-zA-Z]+/[0-9]+/?)+` matches the key value pairs

Comment: I would say that you really need to change design of your API and make at least the keys the request parameters.

Comment: All of the keys are optional.  I was trying to avoid query params.  The REST hierarchy makes a lot more sense to me when the keys are integrated into the URL.

There is another endpoint that responds to keys that are missing values so that the service can provide valid options.